# astyle formatting multiple line <<

Tags: c++, coding-style

I'm using astyle which is great for applying standard style to existing code.  However I've noticed that when it comes across this:

```
ostringstream myStream;
myStream << 1
         << 2;
```

it reformats to this:

```
ostringstream myStream;
myStream << 1
<< 2;
```

Here's my options file: (version 1.23)

> ```
> --indent=spaces
> --brackets=break
> --indent-switches
> --indent-namespaces
> --min-conditional-indent=4
> --break-closing-brackets
> --pad-paren-in
> --unpad-paren
> --convert-tabs
> ```

Is there any way to make it line up the "<<" on the next line?

**Edit:**

I also tried version 1.22 with the following file (test.cpp):

```
void main()
{
    ostringstream myStream;
    myStream << 1
             << 2;
}
```

with the following options (format.txt):

```
--indent=spaces
--brackets=break-closing
--indent-switches
--indent-namespaces
--min-conditional-indent=4
--pad=paren-in
--unpad=paren
--convert-tabs
```

and the following command line:

> astyle --options=format.txt test.cpp

which produced this:

```
void main()
{
    ostringstream myStream;
    myStream << 1
    << 2;
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Final Conclusion is it's a [bug](http://sourceforge.net/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=1713990&group%5Fid=2319&atid=102319)** *see bottom*

<strike>I tried to replicate your problem and was unable to get the behavior you are talking about</strike> (OP question update negates this)

**Edit:** (deleted content to update)

Parameter names have changed between 1.22 and 1.23.

<strike>If neither solves your problem, try uploading more code as an example, or otherwise try to replicate your problem using only the code you pasted here.</strike> (Done by OP)

I've also found that the order of the options seems to have made a difference on occasion. For example:

```
astyle --indent=tab --style=ansi test.cpp
```

is not the same as:

```
astyle --style=ansi --indent=tab test.cpp
```

Specifying the "--style=ansi" second effectively negates the "--indent=tab".

I would not be surprised if this might be your issue.

**...But after playing around with this for 20 min, I'm convinced it's an astyle [bug](http://sourceforge.net/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=1713990&group%5Fid=2319&atid=102319).**

*Edit to include link to bug*: [bug](http://sourceforge.net/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=1713990&group%5Fid=2319&atid=102319) Thanks Markh44

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I was using v1.23 and those options are correct for that version.  I got version 1.22 and changed the options for that version but I get the same problem (see updated question).

Comment: Another bug exists in ver 2.04. It adds an extra newline at the end of any file. It is quite annoying if you use the tool for validating code in a pre-commit step.

Answer (score 2):

@Catskul, you're right, it's a bug.

I eventually found this:

http://sourceforge.net/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=1713990&group_id=2319&atid=102319